# Simple Vue Component doesn't work on first div, only on second div

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm currently trying to learn basic vue.js component. These are my codes

chat.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="components-demo">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">Users</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                <button-counter></button-counter>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="chat-component" class="col-md-9">
                {{--<chat-component v-bind:auth-user="{{$user}}" v-bind:other-user="{{ $otherUser }}"></chat-component>--}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('js')
    <script>
    </script>
@endsection
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap')

window.Vue = require('vue')


// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component(
    'chat-component',
    require('./components/ChatComponent.vue').default
);
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
});


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
new Vue({ el: '#components-demo' });
```

The problem is when i try to click the button, the count is not working. But if I add another same component div with the same id, it works for the button in the second div.

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="components-demo">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Users</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <button-counter></button-counter>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="components-demo">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Users</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <button-counter></button-counter>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Why is it only working on the 2nd div? Is there something that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering multiple Vue instances. You can register many components on single Vue instance.

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap')

window.Vue = require('vue')


// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component(
    'chat-component',
    require('./components/ChatComponent.vue').default
);
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
});


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

You must make sure that the identifier is app in the app.blade.php file.

layouts/app.blade.php

```
...
<body>
   ...
   <div id="app">
      ...
      @yield('content')
      ...
   </div>
   ...
</body>
...
```

Then, your components should work correctly